# Ubuntu 22.04 Unattended Upgrades: apt hook usage, for command execution after successful updates

Tags: apt, upgrade

I looked at the commands executed after a successful update, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

```
# cat 15update-stamp
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"touch /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

So I created a file with the content:

```
# cat 90rpi-firmware-purge
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"find /boot/firmware -type f -name '*.bak' -delete 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

However, after the unattended upgrade runs, the `bak` files are not deleted. Which leads me to believe the actual command is not executed successfully. If I run the command manually as `root` user, the files are deleted.

I noticed that some files use a different hook:

```
# cat 99needrestart
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"test -x /usr/lib/needrestart/apt-pinvoke && /usr/lib/needrestart/apt-pinvoke || true"; };
```

I'm trying to understand where the issue could be. I also remember that Linux requires the full path to executable, in a script, `/usr/bin/find` instead of `find`. Looking at the above listed commands, no full path is defined for executables.

I don't see any errors into `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` file, where should I look for any possible post-update execution errors? Thank you for your help.

Edit: I think I understand the differences, while looking at the comments, `DPkg::Post-Invoke` when dpkg is called, we might have different updates, or `APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success` when apt cache is updated:

```
# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit
// THIS FILE IS USED TO INFORM PACKAGEKIT
// THAT THE UPDATE-INFO MIGHT HAVE CHANGED

// Whenever dpkg is called we might have different updates
// i.e. if an user removes a package that had an update
DPkg::Post-Invoke {
"/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null";
};

// When Apt's cache is updated (i.e. apt-cache update)
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {
"/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null";
};
```